# Function being removed from object during return

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add an abort function to my promise in Angular.  When debugging the code, I can see the function gets added as expected.  However, when the object is returned to the calling service, the function is no longer there.  I'm hoping it's something trivial.

```
.factory('MatchmakerSearch', ['$resource', 'OBB_ENV_CONF', '$q', function ($resource, 
  OBB_ENV_CONF, $q) {
  // Create the $resource object to handle the API requests
  function _query(params) {
    var _deferredAbort = $q.defer();

    var _request = $resource(OBB_ENV_CONF.API_HOST + 'int/matchMaker', {}, {
      'query': {
        method: 'GET',
        params: params,
        isArray: false,
        timeout: _deferredAbort.promise
      }
    });

    var _promise = _request.query().$promise.then( // Convert from $resource to $http
      function (response) {
        return response;
      }, function (response) {
        return $q.reject('Ajax call aborted');
      }
    );

    _promise.abort = function () {
      _deferredAbort.resolve();
    };

    _promise.finally(function () {
      _promise.abort = angular.noop;
      _deferredAbort = _request = _promise = null;
    });

    return _promise; // <~~~~ abort function exists here
   }
   return {
     query: _query
   }
 }
]);
```

The service making the call looks like this:

```
_searchRequest = MatchmakerSearch.query(buildQueryParams()).then(function (result) { 
 // <~~~~ _searchRequest does not contain an abort() function.
  });
```

I really thought this would be a simple thing to code.  Any ideas on why my function is disappearing on return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you chain a promise with `then`, `catch`, or `finally` you receive a new Promise back:

```
_searchRequest = MatchmakerSearch
    .query(buildQueryParams())  // Your customised promise.
    .then(function (result) {}) // a new promise returned here.
```

So `_searchRequest` ends up being a fresh new Promise instance.

The [documentation for `deferred.then()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) talks about this:

> then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback) – ...
>
> This method *returns a new promise* which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback ...

(Emphasis in the original)